# Where are python3 modules

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, module, mariadb

I'm trying to run a sample database connection my mariadb database.

```
  python3 sample.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 3, in <module>
    import mysql.connector as mariadb
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

I have installed the python3-mysql.connector.

```
sudo apt-get -y install python3-mysql.connector
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3-mysql.connector is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using pip to install Python modules:

`sudo pip3 install mysql-connector`

Your Python program should then be able to use the module.